# Unable to remove empty column names in the datatable in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net, oledbcommand

I have an Excel which business users will update and send it to us. Blue Prism robot will pick the file and upload into SQL database table using code stage (it is much faster to use code stage). I have written C# code to do this, however most of the time its failing due to white space in the column.

It results when the code uses used range it take white space as well and creates the data table with column name F16, F17 ... (when the column count is 15)

I wanted to handle this dynamically. i.e irrespective of column count and white space column count, the code should work by removing those white space columns from data tables

I have written code to handle this but it didn't work. It throws an error:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute [duplicate]

```
try
{
    string excelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", Path);
    using (OleDbConnection xlConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString)) 
    { 
        OleDbCommand oleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand ("Select * FROM [" + SheetName + "$]", xlConnection); 

        xlConnection.Open(); 

        // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet 
        using (DbDataReader dbDtRdr = oleDbCmd.ExecuteReader()) 
        { 
                //Remove Empty Rows
                var dtTable = new DataTable();
                dtTable.Load(dbDtRdr);

                for (int i = dtTable.Rows.Count - 1; i>=0;i--)
                {
                    if(dtTable.Rows[i][1] == DBNull.Value)
                        dtTable.Rows[i].Delete();
                }

                dtTable.AcceptChanges();

                //Remove Empty Columns
                int z = 1;

                foreach(DataRow r in dtTable.Rows)
                {
                    foreach(DataColumn c in dtTable.Columns)
                    {   
                        if (c.ColumnName=="F" + z.ToString())
                            dtTable.Columns.Remove(c.ColumnName);
                    }
                }

                dtTable.AcceptChanges();

                // SQL Server Connection String 
                string sqlConnectionString = @"Data Source=" + SQLServerName + ";Initial Catalog=" + SQLDBName + ";Integrated Security=True"; 

                // Bulk Copy to SQL Server 
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString)) 
                { 
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = TableName; 
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtTable); 
                }
        } 

        xlConnection.Close();
    }

    Success = true;
    Message = "Success";
}
catch (System.IO.IOException e)
{
    Message = e.Message;
    Success = false;        
}
```

It looks like I am unable to delete any columns in the data table using remove command in the above code

It would be great help if someone help me on this.

Note: I tried using For Next loop to reiterate it backward like below and still faced an issue

```
                for (int z = dtTable.Columns.Count - 1; z>=0;z--)
                    {
                            if (dtTable.Columns[z].ColumnName.ToString()=="F" + (z).ToString())
                            dtTable.Columns.Remove(dtTable.Columns[z].ColumnName.ToString());
                        }
                        dtTable.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: If you think about it, you're looping through each DataColumn and then also removing from that Collection at the same time, which cannot happen. You need a For loop, and then loop backwards to 0 (which you can see happening just above that line).  General rule of thumb: not a good idea to remove from a collection you're looping through at the same time, unless you work your way backwards.

Comment: There is no reason to loop through the DataRows if you are looking for a column.  You don't have to loop through the DataColumns either, since you just need to see if a column exists, and if it does, remove that.  No loops required.

Comment: @LarsTech I have trimming both empty rows and columns. Rows working fine but not columns.

Comment: @JohnPete22 Thanks for your valuable input. I tried using this earlier but didn't work. Now I realized why since I used if (dtTable.Columns[z].ColumnName.ToString()=="F" + (z).ToString()) however it should be if (dtTable.Columns[z].ColumnName.ToString()=="F" + (z+1).ToString()) since the additional whitespace name using the index of 1 and not 0 for columns. Please post your comment as answer and I can mark this as resolved

Comment: Glad you got it resolved.  Another nitpick: i'd recommend using a string.compare instead of the ==. ````int z = 1;
        if (string.Compare("ColumnName", string.Format("F{0}", z + 1), StringComparison.InvariantCulture) == 0){
            // code to execute
        }````

Comment: To add...if you don't care about letter casing, you can use ````StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase```` as the third parameter in the comparison.

Comment: Thanks John for the recommendation. I have added. Can you pls update your comment in answer section so that I can close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment given by JohnPete22 given below, its working fine

> If you think about it, you're looping through each DataColumn and then also removing from that Collection at the same time, which cannot happen. You need a For loop, and then loop backwards to 0 (which you can see happening just above that line). General rule of thumb: not a good idea to remove from a collection you're looping through at the same time, unless you work your way backwards

Also below point should be noted

> I have tried using John's solution earlier but didn't work. Then I realised that I have used if (dtTable.Columns[z].ColumnName.ToString()=="F" + (z).ToString()) however it should be if (dtTable.Columns[z].ColumnName.ToString()=="F" + (z+1).ToString()) since the additional white space name using the index of 1 and not 0 for columns.